# How do I use the $substr expression in $project operator when using MongoDB 3.0 Java Driver aggregation framework

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, substr

I am attempting to integrate a mongoDB process into Java but can't wrap my head around how to integrate the $expressions within the $project operator whilest using the aggregation framework. The perfectly working Mongo query is:

```
db.options.aggregate([{$project:{name:1,lastTradeDate:1,month:{$substr:["$lastTradeDate",4,2]}}},{$out:"Books"}])
```

Converting this to Java has got me to the following (non-functioning) point:

```
Document expression = new Document("$substr", new Document("lastTradeDate",new int[] {4,2}));
        AggregateIterable iterable = myDocs.aggregate(asList(
                new Document("$project", new Document("name", 1).append("lastTradeDate", 1).append("month", expression)),
                new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$contSize").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))));
```

So the question is: how do I ge the 'expression' to actually be recognized as an expression of the $substr type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same problem. I found that [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) gave the flexibility I was after without the convoluted way of having to implement this directly.

The resulting jongo query looks something like the following:

```
Aggregate.ResultsIterator<JongoDoc> jongoProject = JongoColl.aggregate("{$project:{name:1, smonth:{$substr:['$lastTradeDate',4,2]}}}").and("{$out:'Books'}").as(JongoDoc.class);
```

Comment: Hello @VJ Smits, the Jongo was not able to parse the expression(projection)

Answer (score 0):

For $substr in $project operator, you can form query the following way:

In mongodb, considering a document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a09b076560a311779be35f"),
    "name" : "Helen",
    "date" : "12-04-2015",
    "description" : "Committee head"
}
```

Consider you need only day to be projected from "date" field. The aggregate query using java query is as follows:

```
Document dayExpression = new Document("$substr", Arrays.asList("$date", 0, 2));

AggregateIterable<BasicDBObject> iterable = coll.aggregate(Arrays
                .asList(new Document("$project", new Document("name", 1)
                                .append("description", 1),
                                .append("dayOfDate", dayExpression))));
```